# Show/Move main window at custom position

Tags: windows, go, fyne

#### Problem

I can't find function to set position of the window. I'v looked into code and I see `SetPos` func for different elements and wondering why it's not added for `fyne.Window` type.

```golang
func main() {
    a := app.New()
    w := a.NewWindow("Trying to position window")

    if drv, ok := fyne.CurrentApp().Driver().(desktop.Driver); ok {
        w = drv.CreateSplashWindow()
        // something like this?
        // w.SetPos(x, y)  
        // w.Move(x, y)    
    }
```

##### Workaround

I forked project and created func:

```golang
func (w *window) GLFWindow() *glfw.Window {
    return w.view()
}
```

to expose unexported underlying window attribute `w.viewport`. and it unlocks bunch of methods i can use now

```golang
if ww := w.GLFWindow(); ww != nil {
    ww.SetPos(x, y)
}
```

It looks I'm gonna use it (forked/edited version) but maybe you can suggest *fyne-way* to do it :)

#### Question

Is there existing way to set position of the window? Or access underlying `w.viewport` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the exported API, because many OS do not support it.
See discussion about the decision process at https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne/issues/1155

Comment: ok. so i'm going to use my fork. Seems odd to not allow use that underlying window attribute.

Comment: Did you read the thread? It isn’t supported on some platforms and we don’t want to mislead developers by exposing an API that may not work.

Comment: I've read the thread, but I was in a "denial" phase and wanted a second/underground opinion here on Stack Overflow. Also, I think Fyne could have some functionality to expose some underlying attributes "at my own risk." Or, a different branch with exposed GLFW.Window. But I understand, don't risk a bug overflow after too many users use an "unstable" branch.